# Microsoft enterprise library exception handling block using log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net, enterprise-library

I am bound to use log4net due to management decisions.

Is it possible for me to use log4net just for logging within Enterprise Library Exception handling block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just write a custom handler. We show how to do it in the [Extensibility labs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13738) (labs 1 and 2).